# Adding a new line Richtextbox

Tags: vb.net, newline, richtextbox, stringbuilder

Can anyone correct me on what is wrong with this code?
I can't add a new line inside Richtextbox control

```
Dim sb = New System.Text.StringBuilder()
        sb.Append("{\rtf1\ansi")
        sb.Append("\b " & TextBox2.Text & "\b0" & Environment.NewLine & "my body")
        sb.Append("}")
        Textbox.Rtf = sb.ToString
```

Comment: is you textbox set to multiine?

Answer (score 1):

Because you aren't using rtf codes.  Try:

```
sb.Append("\b " & TextBox2.Text & "\b0\par my body")
```